# Docker Compose Multiple Containers

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-python

I have a Python script which connects to MySql and inserts data into a database.That is the one container, I want to build. I want to build another container which will have a Python script which will connect to the database of the first container and execute some queries. I am trying to follow the documentation of Docker, however I find it difficult to make the proper yml file. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you show us what you have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex is what you want to make, but the docker-compose.yml file should look similar to this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  my_database:
    image: mysql
    [... MySQL configs]


  my_python_container:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - my_database
    links:
      - my_database
```

I have not knowledge about the configuration of the MySQL database so I left that part blank (`[... MySQL configs]`).
The my_python_conainer is in a Dockerfile in the same folder, similar to:

```
FROM python
COPY script.py script.py
CMD python script.py
```

This should be enough to get the connection, but you have to consider in your program that the mysql hostname will be the name given to the container.